# Click on anything in Windows 7 does not work

Tags: windows-7

So I have the same problem as described in this discussion from a few years ago:
[Cannot click on anything in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/629649/cannot-click-on-anything-in-windows-7)
and after CTRL-ALT-DEL and hitting CANCEL, this solves the problem - but only temporarily. Sometimes 20 secs, sometimes a minute or two, and the problem is back.

Anyone knows how to solve this permanently?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: What have you tried? Scan for malware? Checking Task Manager?

Comment: Yes, I did a scan - nothing was found.  Not sure what I should be checking in the Task Manager? Processes and services running in the background? I honestly do not know what most of these are and what they are doing. But I somehow do not think that this problem has anything to do with spy- or malware.

Comment: Do a clean boot and then see if the issue still happens. This can identify if the application or service that is causing such issue.

Comment: Did a clean boot and no change.  Problem persists.  Really not sure what to do next.